# Self avoiding walks and context free languages

Tags: co.combinatorics, graph-theory, formal-languages

Let $G$ be an infinite, locally finite, connected graph whose arcs (oriented edges) are labelled by letters in a finite alphabet $\Sigma$ such that arcs starting in the same vertex are labelled by different letters. Then every self avoiding walk starting at a given vertex $o$ can be encoded as a string over the alphabet $\Sigma$ (by reading the labels of arcs along the walk), denote the language of all such strings by $L_{\mathrm{SAW(o)}}$.

Assume that the labelled graph $G$ is quasi-transitive, that is, the group of label-preserving automorphisms acts with finitely many orbits on the set of vertices. It is known that if $L_{\mathrm{SAW(o)}}$ is a [context free language](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Context-free_language), then so is $L_{\mathrm{SAW(o')}}$ for any other vertex $o'$ of $G$.

**Question:** Is there an elementary/direct proof of this fact? Perhaps even one that does not require quasi-transitivity? Clearly, it is enough to prove it for the case when $o'$ is a neighbour of $o$.

The only proof I am aware of is based on a characterisation of graphs with context free $L_{\mathrm{SAW(o)}}$ from the paper  [The language of self avoiding walks](https://arxiv.org/abs/1903.02368) by C. Lindorfer and W. Woess. They show that $L_{\mathrm{SAW(o)}}$ is context free if and only if all ends of $G$ have size at most two (and the latter condition does not depend on $o$).